# add link to website in Gallery Formatter

Tags: jquery, css, drupal, module, hyperlink

I built a portfolio website using [Gallery Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter) with Drupal 7.x and I was wondering if I somehow can add a link icon to each gallery item that the user on click would bring to another website..?
Any hints, tips and assistance is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't get this figured out so i just went ahead and used a different design for me portfolio gallery